# How can values be assigned to the output of is.na()?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, na, assignment-operator

Following is related to R language.

```
x1 <- c(1, 4, 3, NA, 7)
is.na(x1) <- which(x1 == 7)
```

I don't undertand, the LHS in last line gives you a vector of boolean and RHS is a value(index where x ==7, 5 in this case). So what does it mean to assign a boolean vector a value of 5?

Comment: read ?is.na carefully. it's a very confusing function TBH and I have yet to actually use it

Answer (score 0):

`is.na` from the docs returns:

> The default method for is.na applied to an atomic vector returns a logical vector of the same length as its argument x, containing TRUE for those elements marked NA or, for numeric or complex vectors, NaN, and FALSE otherwise.

Therefore, by making a logical vector(you're in essence saying wherever an index is `TRUE`, this should be an `NA`.

By "matching" these indices to the corresponding index from `which`, you're turning the latter into `NA`s wherever `FALSE` hence the change.

To put it in practice:

This is the output from `is.na(x1)`:

```
is.na(x1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The corresponding output from `which(x==7)`:

```
which(x1 == 7)
[1] 5
```

**Combining, the element at position 5 will now become an `NA` because it has been given the logical `is.na()` which returns `TRUE`**

```
is.na(x1) <- which(x1 == 7)
 x1
[1]  1  4  3 NA NA
```

The above turns the first index into an `NA`  and `appends` two more `NA`s so as to make index 7 and `NA`.

This can be best seen by:

```
is.na(x1) <- c(1,7)
 x1
[1] NA  4  3 NA  7 NA NA
```

Compare with this example from the docs:

```
(xx <- c(0:4))
is.na(xx) <- c(2, 4)
 xx
[1]  0 NA  2 NA  4
```

From the above, it is clear that c(2,4) follows the original indices in `xx` hence the rest become `NA`s.

Comment: Isn't it weird? I have never noticed such behavior in languages I have worked on. a.) In LHS (is.na(x)),  we just have a boolean vector and not x. We don't have access to the variable x. b.) And it not just about (which(x==7), even if you directly write 5 on the RHS, the result will be same. It is essentially boiling down to:

c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE) = 5

which is wrong.

Comment: You're setting an index to `NA`. If you use 5, it sets index 5 as NA. The main point is that we're working with indices not values.

Comment: I am sorry, i think you are not getting my point. The two commands when evaluated separately and rewritten are nothing but c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE) = 5. How can this be true? I think R has made some special provisions to work with the output of is.na(). Otherwise, it does not make any sense.

Comment: Please read my answer(again??) and let me know and let me know where I should specifically re-elaborate.